# How to return a value from a service in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that the data is coming from the server (I have unit tests and have seen the data in the debugger in chrome) but I can't figure out how to return the data from the angular service to the angular controller.

Service:

**UPDATED**

```
surchargeIndex.service('customerService', [
'$http', function ($http) {
    this.getTest = function () {
       return $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "api/Customer/GetTest",
            })
            .success(function(data) {
                return data;
            });
    };
}
```

]);

Controller:

```
surchargeIndex.controller('SurchargeIndexController', function ($scope, customerService, templateService) {
    $scope.customers = customerService.getTest();

});
```

Data has the array from the server so the array is populated in the service. So to reiterate the data is there; however, I receive a 404 error INSIDE of the success handler during debugging.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$http` works asynchronously; fortunately it returns a promise which will be fulfilled when the response retrieved from the server. So you should return $http's get method and use returned promise to handle data.

```
this.getTest = function () {
        return $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "api/Customer/GetTest",
            })
            .success(function(data) {
                return data;
            })
            .error(function() {
                alert("failed");
        }); // This returns a promise

    };
```

Then in your controller you should use that promise to retrieve the expected data.

```
surchargeIndex.controller('SurchargeIndexController', function ($scope, customerService, templateService) {
    //Use the returned promise to handle data, first parameter of the promise is used for successful result, if error happens, second parameter of the promise returns the error and you can do your error handling in that function
    customerService.getTest().then(function(customers){$scope.customers = customers;},   function(err){console.error(err);})
});
```

Comment: You say it returns a "promise", what does that mean?

Comment: As you may know javascript works asynchronously, so when you make a request through `$http` the process does not stop till it returns a result, but it continues with the next command. By returning a promise, you give a hook to the caller. Promise will be fulfilled when a respone is retrieved from the server, and the client will be notified using promise's `then` function. You may want to check https://github.com/kriskowal/q which is one of the widely used promise implementations.

Comment: Okay so data has the array but it is not returned to the controller. I get a into the success handler but when I debug it I receive a 404 on return data inside of the success handler

Comment: 404 means that the requested path which is 'api/Customer/GetTest' does not exists in the asked server, can you check that path? Could you make a request from http client such as postman?

Comment: You need the `.then()` described by cubbuk in your controller. The promise never gets to your controller without that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a Callback to get your data "back" to your controller, after an async http call... There are different ways to do... I will show you one way without a callback, or a promise, but the best way would be to use a callback, or promise...

Wild West Way:

```
app.controller('myCTRL', function($scope, myService) {

       $scope.valueWanted = myService.valueWanted;
       myService.getData();

});

app.service('myService', function($http) {

       var myThis = this;

       this.valueWanted = "";
       this.getData = function () {
              $http.get('api/Customer/GetTest').success(function (data) {
                     myThis.valueWanted = data.valueWanted;
              });
       };

});
```